# Transaction in SQL server agent job schedule

Tags: sql-server, ssis

I have 6 ssis packages. All packages are for loading flat files into sql server table. I have created a sql server agent job to automate the flat file load process and put all packes exxecution in different steps. If the first file fails to load into the SQL server table, all the succeeding steps (packages) should not execute. Can I create a transaction to in sql server agent to do this?

Thank you for your help and time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change your job step to "Quit the job reporting failure" for the On Failure setting.  No need for transactions at all.

Comment: Can I ask you one more question? suppose If first file (Step 1) and second  file (Step2) are loaded into SQL server tables, but the 3rd file () did not load. So I want to rollback all the steps (I mean step 1 and step 2). How Can I do that?

Comment: You would need to change the way your packages are constructed.  Agent has no knowledge of transactions, just job status.  The best way would be to have a master package that calls a bunch of child packages (each step) and have them all in sequence containers with the proper transaction setting for each one.